# Can I use .NET 4.6 for main domain and .NET Core for api

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core

So I've developed a standard .NET 4.6 CRUD app that adds / edits / deletes data in a SQL Express database and is hosted on Azure. This will only be used by a couple of people to manage data for the main project which will be a one page Angular / mobile app. The next step is to develop an api (with .NET Core) so the data can be consumed by the Angular / mobile app.

What I'm wondering is if I already have the main CRUD app created with .NET 4.6, can I create an api in the same domain using .NET Core? Something like this:

mydomain.com - .NET 4.6
mydomain.com/api - .NET Core

Comment: The question is completely unrelated to either ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core nor .NET Core. It's a matter how you configure your Webserver (IIS, Ngnix, etc.). NET Core applications run on their own and IIS (or nginx) only act as a reverse proxy)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Angular so I removed that tag.

Comment: [Asking "is it possible" is typically a shortcut to asking "how can I"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270933/215552). If that is the case here, the question is too broad. If you are really asking "is it possible" the answer is "try it and see".

Comment: @Tseng thanks for the feedback. I don't see how it's "completely unrelated" to ASP.NET or .NET Core, seeing as that's what I'm using to develop both applications. I wanted to know if there was anything that would prevent me deploying and running the app and the api as I described.

Comment: Thanks @Mike McCaughan, I was playing around with this setup locally and was getting a variety of errors and timeouts, so I wanted to see if anyone has used this deployment setup before and if it was possible, if there were any gotchas or things to look out for etc.

Comment: Because its a configuration of your webserver/loadbalancer, which has to look at the path and decide to which application to route the traffic to. In IIS its called virtual folders, in nginx its called virtual hosts and for Azure its more or less configurable via application gateway (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-introduction) under the name of "url routing"

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do this, you can also run a node.js app on `mydomain.com/api_js` for that matter, it's all about how do you configure your web server.

If it's a question how to configure the web server, you need just to google about your particular web server.

If it's a question if that makes sense - in my opinion yes, MS is putting now so much effort in being multi-platform, that my bet would be on the .NET Core being more future proof.

Only you have to keep in mind, that it won't be a simple reference adding to reuse the code, as it's not possible to reference `.NET 4.x` assemblies from a `.NET Core` project.

But it's possible the other way around, so you can abstract away the code you want to reuse from your `.NET 4.6` project into a shared `.NET Core` assembly, which than may be referenced by both projects.